# mongoimport json file doubles the number of doucuments

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I was trying to use mongoimport to import a json file into mongodb.
The json file is formatted as one document per line, something like:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"feature0","geometry":{},"properties":{}}  
{"type":"Feature","id":"feature1","geometry":{},"properties":{}}
```

And I used `mongoimport --db mydb --collection mycollection data.json` on command line, and got:

```
2015-04-24T23:48:09.351+0800    connected to: localhost  
2015-04-24T23:48:09.495+0800    imported 4085 documents
```

But when I used mongo shell and tried `db.mycollection.find().count()` I got 8170. The number of documents has been doubled.

Then I tried to find documents with "id"(not "_id") and I got two same results except for "_id".

So why have the documents been saved twice?

Comment: Have you tried using [--upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsert) on import? Might also be that by default mongoose uses `_id` not `id` for uniqueness. You can use `--upsertFields` to specify (same link as above).

Comment: Thanks Tony, `--upsert` will do the trick. I'm not sure whether it just inserts the json documents once and then updates them, but because nothing changes in the update so I've got the desired result. Still I wonder why I've got a copy of the documents without specifying `--upsert`.

Comment: The duplicates happen because mongo tries to find existing records via `_id`. But, your data doesn't have that field and you don't appear to be telling mongo that. So it sees new records and just inserts them again.

Comment: Eh, but I only got one copy of the records in my file, which is 4085 documents, just like the info `2015-04-24T23:48:09.495+0800    imported 4085 documents` indicates, so it seems that mongodb has imported the same records twice.

Comment: Did you run the command more than once while testing or whatnot? Otherwise, I'm at a loss.

Comment: "The duplicates happen because mongo tries to find existing records via _id. But, your data doesn't have that field and you don't appear to be telling mongo that." Tony, I have this same problem, probably for the same reason. Could you expand on how you tell mongo about your lack of _id, and how to work around that? Thanks.